# asp:label text not updated on page_load, getting updated only on refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net

In aspx file,

```
<small id="liOTN" clientidmode="Static" style="display: none;position: relative;" runat="server">&nbsp;For help call&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblATN" runat="server"/>&nbsp;</small>
```

In Page_Load,

```
lblATN.Text = "9999999999";
liOTN.Style.Add("display", "block");
liOTN.Visible = true;
```

While loading the page, we are just getting the "For help call", "9999999999" is not displayed. But when we refresh the same page, it is working fine ("For help call 9999999999").

Comment: Have you also tried adding `liOTN.Style["display"] = "block";` ?

Comment: liOTN.Style.Add("display", "block"); It is already there